# Custom Translator error minimum sentence requirement

Tags: microsoft-translator

Is there a requirement to have at least 10,000 sentences to create a model? I only have under 70 utterances for Hindi/English sentences. 
Thanks,
Jaya

Answer (score 1):

Yes for a full training you need 10000 sentences. But you can build a dictionary model using phrase or sentence documents.
[image: Upload documents]